# how to run Truecrypt after installation

Tags: truecrypt

I have installed truecrypt on ma Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I can see the icon of truecrypt when i search on the doc.But on clicking on the icon I am not able to run the software or no responses coming when I try to open the software by clicking the icon.what could be the reason ? or how should I run the same ?

Note :

When I tried to run  truecrypt from terminal it shows

```
bash: /usr/bin/truecrypt: cannot execute binary file
```

and when I tried sudo  truecrypt it shows

```
/usr/bin/truecrypt: 1: /usr/bin/truecrypt: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Comment: Please run `truecrypt` from a terminal window and post the output you get. It may help to diagnose the problem (some missing library, wrong architecture, etc).

Comment: What version of Truecrypt did you install? What exact steps did you follow?

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-truecrypt-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-debian-fedora-and-opensuse/

Comment: I had found the answer, That was some problem caused due to the error in source file..so I re-installed it with following ..it worked perfectly
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-astrapi/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install truecrypt